# How to post Image to Twitter with Rest API in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, twitter, twitter-rest-api

In my app the user should upload a picture to Twitter (with the Rest API).
Now the user can only tweet with text but this works with this code:

```
let textToTweet = textView.text

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

    let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, URL: url, parameters: ["status": textToTweet!])
    request.account = twitterAccount
    request.performRequestWithHandler { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if response.statusCode != 200 {

            print("not working")

        }
    }
```

Now I wanted to take a step forward and used this, but it´s not working with this code. :

```
 let textToTweet = textView.text
    let imageToTweet = image.image

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json")

    let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, URL: url, parameters: ["status": textToTweet!, "media[]": imageToTweet!])

    request.account = twitterAccount
    request.performRequestWithHandler { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if response.statusCode != 200 {

            print(error)

        }
    }
```

Here´s the information that gives Twitter about [POST statuses/update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media). The console is showing "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and the app isn´t posting the post or the image.
Thank you!

Comment: Start by printing the actual error message instead of printing "not working". It will help you understand what is happening.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks! It say´s "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: `imageToTweet` is probably `nil`, and it crashes the app because you're using force-unwrapping with `!` to extract its value.

Comment: It´s not nil there is an image and it´s not crashing

Comment: `It´s not nil there is an image`: did you verify this? The compiler tells you that you **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. If it's not this one, it's the other one (textToTweet). But since you said text works, it must be the image one. // Oh, and your app *does* crash. Otherwise you wouldn't get this error message...

Comment: I set the image in the viewDidLoad() and it´s showing the right one. And with "print(textToTweet)" it show´s the right text in the console...

Comment: How can I check that there is this image once again? I´m sorry your right the app is crashing...forgot that the app stops while testing

Comment: I´ve renamed the image and it´s still not working

Comment: @EricD. Even if the textView is empty and i click the button it show´s this error and not the "photo or text is nil" message

Comment: Ok, I've deleted my answer since the error doesn't actually come from these two forced-unwrapped properties. But given the content of the error message, the error you have *is* an Optional which is nil and then forced-unwrapped. // I just had a look at your link, and... look: **POST statuses/update_with_media (deprecated) - This endpoint has been DEPRECATED. Please use [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) for uploading one or more media entities.** That would explain why you get nil... !!  :)

Comment: @EricD. Thank you! I did not saw it....But with this code it´s still not working:/ `let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
        if let txt = textView.text, let img = imageView.image {
            let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, URL: url, parameters: ["status": txt, "media_ids": img])
                request.account = twitterAccount
` The app is only posting the text but without any crash or issue...

Comment: I think you have to use POST media/upload endpoint to first upload the media files the response would be a media_id. Use that meda_id (could be multiple if multiple images are uploaded) to compose the tweet in the POST status/update parameter.